# How to formulate intra-day return?

Tags: time-series, price, capital-returns, bitcoin

So I have time series data on the bitcoin price. For each day there is an open price and a close price. In many papers they calculae the return like this:
$$ R_t = \Delta P  / P_{t-1} = ln(P_t/P_{t-1}) $$
This is more like a day on day return.

I calculated it like this:
$$ R_t = ln( Close_t / Open_t ) $$
I would call it an intra-day return. Is this an appropriate way to do it and how can I formulate this in a mathematical correct way?

Answer (score 1):

It is an approximation, but it is appropriate for *small* values (i.e. returns close to zero, what exactly *small* means depends on the precision you want to achieve) and it comes from the first order Taylor expansion of logarithmic function.

The correct way to compute a return, calling $P_t$ and $P_{t-1}$ final and initial price, is:

$$
R_t=\frac{P_t-P_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}}
$$

Now, let's consider $x=\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}$.

The first order Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ around $x_0$ is:

$$
f(x)\approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\left(x-x_0\right)
$$

By substituting $f(x)$ with $ln(x)$, considering that the derivative of $ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ and taking $x_0=1$, you get:
$$
ln(x)\approx ln(1)+\left(x-1\right)
$$

$$
ln(x)\approx x-1
$$

Substituting:

$$
ln(\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}})\approx \frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}-1
$$

$$
ln(\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}})\approx \frac{P_t-P_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}}=R_t
$$

Which completes the proof.

Comment: And how can I apply this to my case where $$P_t = Close_t$$ and $$P_{t-1} = Open_t$$. Also isn't $$P_t - P_{t-1} =  ΔP$$

Comment: I am not sure I understood the problem, what do you mean with "Also isnt' ..."?

Comment: I meant: Isn't the following true? Sorry :D

Comment: This answer seems to address a different question than the one asked.

Comment: @RichardHardy can you explain why it is not an answer? He asked if its representation of returns was appropriate and a way to show it in a mathamatical correct way.

Comment: @BlankerHans Yes, it is true, to apply to your case just substitute "P_t" with "Close_t" and "P_t-1" with "Open_t".

Comment: @Don I am unsure about it because the time index is little bit messed up isn't it? close_t = p_t-1 seems not right.

Comment: @Don, your answer focuses on log- vs. % returns, but the question is about intra-day vs. daily returns. Your later comment goes in the right direction, I think.

Comment: @BlankerHans Time index shouldn't be messed up if you consider "Δt" as 24 hours. If closure and opening prices are taken at the same hour, just consider "close_(t-1)=opening_t", (Bitcoin is negotiated 24h/day).